# Order values from join with group by

Tags: sql

Context:
The accesoirescondition exist of three fixed condition values. These conditions are representing the state of the accesoires of the product. I got a GROUP BY on product.productid and would only see the most serious accesoires condition for that specific product.

Desired situation:

```
PRODUCTID   PRODUCTNAME     ACCESOIRESID    ACCESOIRESCONDITION
1           product1        2               defect
2           product2        3               working
3           product3        6               working
```

Comment: As Filipe has tried to suggest, you need to apply a value that SQL can understand to evaluate what is the 'Most serious' condition.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a table, rather than a redundant field, for the conditioncode like this:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  productid int,
  productname varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE cond (
  conditionid int,
  conditionname varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE accesoires (
  accesoiresid int,
  productid int,
  accesoiresname varchar(20),
  accesoirescondition int
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
(1, 'product1'),
(2, 'product2'),
(3, 'product3');

INSERT INTO cond VALUES
(1, 'defect'),
(2, 'obsolete'),
(3, 'working');

INSERT INTO accesoires VALUES
(1, 1, 'accesoires1', 3),
(2, 1, 'accesoires2', 1),
(3, 1, 'accesoires3', 2),
(4, 2, 'accesoires4', 3),
(5, 3, 'accesoires5', 3),
(6, 3, 'accesoires6', 2);
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT p.productid, 
       p.productname,
       a.accesoiresid,
       c.conditionname
  FROM product p 
  JOIN accesoires a on p.productId = a.productId
  JOIN cond c on c.conditionid = a.accesoirescondition
 WHERE a.accesoirescondition =
       (SELECT MIN(accesoirescondition) 
          FROM accesoires 
         WHERE productId = p.productId )
```

The result is:

```
PRODUCTID   PRODUCTNAME ACCESOIRESID    CONDITIONNAME
1           product1    2               defect
2           product2    4               working
3           product3    6               obsolete
```

Which looks a lot like your desired output, expect for AccesoiresId in line 2. But that can *never* be 3 with the data you provided (there *IS* no record like that in Accesoires for productid =2)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1db44/4

Comment: implemented your version, still i have a COUNT(a.productid) problem that is only counting for,give back one row, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1db44/10

Comment: in that one, add `group by p.productID, p.productname, a.accesoiresid, c.conditionname`. You need a group by if you use aggregate functions. The result is not what yuo want hough, because there already was only one record per product returned (s the count will be 1 always). But that is a new issue i think :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
 select
    a.productid , 
    a.productname , 
    b.accesoiresid ,
    b.accesoirescondition
from product a
left join accesoires b on a.productid=b.productid
inner join 
(
  select d.productid, min(case 
        when d.accesoirescondition = 'defect'
          then 1
        when d.accesoirescondition = 'obsolete'
          then 2
        when d.accesoirescondition = 'working'
          then 3
        end) as severity
  from accesoires d
  group by d.productid
) c on b.productid = c.productid 
       and c.severity = 
        case 
          when b.accesoirescondition = 'defect'
            then 1
          when b.accesoirescondition = 'obsolete'
            then 2
          when b.accesoirescondition = 'working'
            then 3
        end
```

This will give you the more severe results for each of the products.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4392d/103)</kbd>

Comment: @SecretSquirrel. Why is that?

Comment: well if you use the original data which was provided and add your `order by` clause to the end it does not get the desired result.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel. in original data the results are all 'working', if you get some results where there are other states you can see that they are ordered correctly

Comment: @SecretSquirrel. ah . i see. he doesn't want only to order by, but he only wants the one with max severity. i misread this.

Comment: Indeed 'the product accesoires with the most serious condition'

Comment: @user2952495. see if my new query works for you. I think it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to achieve this I would do what vkamayiannis has done.
However I would suggest storing the conditions in a separate table (`accessoryCondition` in my example)

SQL Example below

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    productid int,
    productname varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE accessories (
    accesoiresid int,
    productid int,
    accesoiresname varchar(20),
    conditiontype int
);


CREATE TABLE accessoryCondition (
    conditiontype int,
    description varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
(1, 'product1'),
(2, 'product2'),
(3, 'product3');

INSERT INTO accessories VALUES
(1, 1, 'accesoires1', 1),
(2, 1, 'accesoires2', 3),
(3, 1, 'accesoires3',  2),
(4, 2, 'accesoires4',  1),
(5, 3, 'accesoires5', 1),
(6, 3, 'accesoires6',  2);

INSERT INTO accessoryCondition VALUES
(1, 'working'),
(3, 'defect'),
(2, 'obsolete');
```

And to hopefully get the result you desire the SQL below, using `JOIN`s to tables

```
select 
  p.productid, 
  p.productname, 
  a.accesoiresid, 
  AC.description
from 
product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
accessories a
ON
p.productid = a.productid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
accessoryCondition AC
ON
A.conditionType = AC.conditiontype
WHERE
  AC.conditiontype IS NULL OR
  AC.conditiontype = 
  (
     select max(a2.conditiontype) 
     from accessories a2
     where a2.productid = a.productid
  )
```

or another way would be to use a nested select like the following

```
SELECT 
    productid,
    productname,
    accesoiresid,
    AC.description AS 'Condition'
FROM
   (
       select 
          p.productid, 
          p.productname, 
          a.accesoiresid,
          MAX(a.conditionType) as 'HighestCondition'
       from 
         product p
       LEFT JOIN
         accessories a
       ON
         p.productid = a.productid
       LEFT JOIN
         accessoryCondition AC
       ON
         A.conditionType = AC.conditiontype
       GROUP BY
         p.productid
     ) products
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    accessoryCondition AC
ON
   products.HighestCondition = AC.conditionType
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use try the decode function:

```
ORDER BY DECODE(accesoires.accesoirescondition ,'defect', 1,
'obsolete', 2, 
'working', 3) ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

I would add another field in table accesoires conditiontype which will be an integer represantation of the condition. Something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  productid int,
  productname varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE accesoires (
  accesoiresid int,
  productid int,
  accesoiresname varchar(20),
  accesoirescondition varchar(20), 
  conditiontype int
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
(1, 'product1'),
(2, 'product2'),
(3, 'product3');

INSERT INTO accesoires VALUES
(1, 1, 'accesoires1', 'working', 1),
(2, 1, 'accesoires2', 'defect', 3),
(3, 1, 'accesoires3', 'obsolete', 2),
(4, 2, 'accesoires4', 'working', 1),
(5, 3, 'accesoires5', 'working', 1),
(6, 3, 'accesoires6', 'obsolete', 2);
```

As you can see the worst condition has a higher number. So my Query would be like:

```
select p.productid, p.productname, a.accesoiresid, a.accesoirescondition
from product p, accesoires a
where p.productid = a.productid
and a.conditiontype = (select max(a1.conditiontype) 
                       from accesoires a1 
                       where a1.productid = a.productid)
```